# How to get a value from a JSON (string) in Groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I have been struggling to figure out how to get a parameter out of a JSON string in Groovy.

I have a string similar to:

```
'{"id":"12345678","name":"Sharon","email":"sharon\u0040example.com"}'
```

and am trying to extract the email address.

I can of course use regex, or other substring methods, but I'm sure there is a cleaner way.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [JsonSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html).

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def str = '{"id":"12345678","name":"Sharon","email":"sharon\u0040example.com"}'
def slurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(str)

assert slurper.email == 'sharon@example.com'
assert slurper.name  == 'Sharon'
```