# Parse rest api content

Tags: json, groovy, rest-client

My rest API returns something like:

```
{"UserInfo":[{"userName":"zbradford","firstName":"Zoe","lastName":"Bradford","emailAddress":"ZBradford@ABC.COM"}]}
```

I would like to let it return only the email address value: `ZBradford@ABC.COM`

Here is my code:

```
    import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

    def slurper = new JsonSlurper()

    def jsonResponse = slurper.parseText(resp)

    jsonResponse.UserInfo.emailAddress.join(',')
```

I got a java null error, any suggestion on my code? Thanks

Comment: Can you post the actual error you get, rather than the anecdotal *'I got a java null error'*

Answer (score 2):

Has to be a json **string** to parse.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def str = '{"UserInfo":[{"userName":"zbradford","firstName":"Zoe",
            "lastName":"Bradford","emailAddress":"ZBradford@ABC.COM"}]}'
def slurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(str)

assert slurper.UserInfo[0].emailAddress == 'ZBradford@ABC.COM'
```

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18345473/2051952).

Comment: Hi dmahapatro, thanks for your response.

In your answer you used a fixed string, but in reality that string used in the question is a variable returned by the rest API, how do I translate it so it works with other variable outputs?

Comment: @user2796831 Almighty of Java has provided a `toString()` on `Object`. If you apply that to the JsonObject shouldn't you get the json string?